# Solve $a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}-5a_{n}=0$ with $a_0=4$ and $a_1=2$ and prove by induction

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

> Solve $$a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}-5a_{n}=0,\quad\text{with $a_0=4$ and $a_1=2$}$$ and prove by induction that the formula found is equivalent to the given.

---

My calculations show that the particular solution is $a_n=3(-1)^{n}+5^{n}$. Now we need to prove it by induction.

For base case, let $n=0$ so $a_0=3+1=4$, and let $n=1$ so $a_1=-3+5=2$. Hence the base case is proven. Now let's see the inductive step:

**What I have done:**

Our hypothesis are: $a_h=3(-1)^h+5^h$ and $a_{h+1}=3(-1)^{h+1}+5^{h+1}$, and we want to show that $a_{h+2}=3(-1)^{h+2}+5^{5+2}$.

*Proof* If $a_{h+2}-4a_{h+1}-5a_{h}=0$ then \begin{align*}a_{h+2}&=4a_{h+1}+5a_{h}\\&=4(3(-1)^{h+1}+5^{h+1})+5(3(-1)^h+5^h)\\&=\color{red}{4\cdot3(-1)^{h+1}}+\color{blue}{4\cdot5^{h+1}}+\color{red}{5\cdot3(-1)^{h}}+\color{blue}{5^{h+1}}\\&=\color{red}{-4\cdot3(-1)^h+5\cdot3(-1)^h}\color{blue}{+5\cdot5^{h+1}}\\&=3(-1)^h+5^{h+2}\\&=3(-1)^2(-1)^h+5^{h+2}\\&=3(-1)^{h+2}+5^{h+2}.&\square\end{align*} **However, my teammate did something quite different:**

He says: $$a_{h+1}=4(5^h+3\cdot(-1)^h) + 5 (5^{h-1}+3\cdot(-1)^{h-1}).$$ I am not sure what he did. I think he assumed something with $a_{h-1}$ and $a_{h}$ but we need $a_{h}$ and $a_{h+1}$ as hypothesis, right?

**How can we help him so he can achieve the correct proof?**

Comment: If you found this formula by direct proof, you do not need to use induction.

Comment: @AlexandreFrias thank you! The statement says "Prove by induction".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your teammate got**
$$a_{h+1}=4(5^h+3\cdot(-1)^h) + 5 (5^{h-1}+3\cdot(-1)^{h-1}) \\
=4 \cdot 5^h+12\cdot(-1)^h + 5 \cdot 5^{h-1}+15\cdot(-1)^{h-1}\\
=4 \cdot 5^h+12\cdot(-1)^h + 5^{h}-15\cdot(-1)^{h}\\
=5 \cdot 5^{h}-3\cdot (-1)^h \\
=5^{h+1} +3 \cdot (-1)^{h+1}$$

Replace $h+1$ by $h+2$ and you'll see that he got exactly the same answer as you, written in a different form.

Not everything which looks different IS different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Why we are able to "Replace $h+1$ by $h+2$"?

Comment: @manooooh If $a_{h+1}=5^{h+1} +3 \cdot (-1)^{h+1}$, then 
$a_{h+2}=???$

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that. What I am not seeing is what we have to prove. What hypothesis do we need?

Comment: I mean, the recurrence relation is of grade $2$ because the difference between the last term and the first one is $2-0=2$. So if we are given $a_{h}$ and $a_{h+1}$, we can find the last term i.e. $a_{h+2}$. This does not happen if the hypothesis are $a_{h-1}$ and $a_{h}$, because we would have to prove $a_{h+1}$ which is of grade $1$.

Comment: ... or maybe $a_{h+1}$ is of grade $2$ because $1-(-1)=2$? Lol.